Why I can't get required OpAmp gain?
I have this basic non-inverting opamp. Input is 20Vpp with required output of 101.8Vpp. LTC6090 seems to fit the bill.
However, to get gain of 5.09, LTSpice simulation shows output is clipping and is more than the required 50.9V (peak amplitude).


Questions:

What is going on here?
Should I select LTC6090 (unity gain stable) or LTC6090-5 (stable in noise gain configurations of 5 or greater)?

Thanks!

Input is 40Vpp. Max VCC is +70, VEE -70. The sim won't care but a real system may fail.

idiot me! i changed it now to 20Vpp and results are all good now. this should work in prototype, fingers crossed.

Your input is 40 Vp-p. The voltage number in the source is peak voltage.

idiot me! i changed it now to 20Vpp and results are all good now. this should work in prototype, fingers crossed.
